# Smarty Error when setting Organization Name in civicrm-4.6.8-wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, installation, 4.6.8

I just setup civicrm 4.6.8 on Wordpress 4.3 "Billie".  I setup my database, and username for Civi to access, and now I'm on the CiviCRM Home screen where it is asking for my `Organization Name`, `Email Address`, and `Default CiviMail Mailbox`.

When I click `Go` next to `Organization Name` I am presented with the following error:

```
Organization Address and Contact Info


Warning: Smarty error: unable to read resource: "CRM/common/stateCountry.tpl" in /srv/www/wordpress-default/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/Smarty/Smarty.class.php on line 1094

Warning: Smarty error: unable to read resource: "CRM/common/stateCountry.tpl" in /srv/www/wordpress-default/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/Smarty/Smarty.class.php on line 1094

Fatal error: Smarty error: [in CRM/common/formButtons.tpl line 38]: [plugin] modifier 'crmBtnValidate' is not implemented (core.load_plugins.php, line 118) in /srv/www/wordpress-default/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/Smarty/Smarty.class.php on line 1094
```

Looking in my `<wordpress>/wp-content/plugins/civicrm` folder does not reveal a packages directory, so I'm uncertain what includes are being requested here.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like some files might be missing in your install. How did you install civicrm plugin?

Packages folder is at /srv/www/wordpress-default/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/

Can you check if /srv/www/wordpress-default/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/templates/CRM/common/stateCountry.tpl file exists?

Comment: When I search core, this file isn't in repo. I don't see here either: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/tree/master/templates/CRM/common Any other reason this error would be there?

Comment: I think that file was deleted a while back. Smarty might be caching old template files. I would try deleting template_c folder and see if that fixes the error